# Getting output from server side python script

Tags: javascript, python, scripting, xmlhttprequest

Hey, I'm doing this project where we are supposed to connect a javascript client side application/web page on server A with a python server side script on server B.

I need to get the output from the python script and store it into a variable but am running into some problems. I was trying to use XMLHttpRequest for this, and even though I managed to establish the connection the return value from the script is always "", an empty string, and it shouldn't be.

Does anyone know what the issue might be here and how to solve it?

P.S. I've been hinted that it might have something to do with cross-server scripting security or something like that, I'm not sure if that helps.

Thanks

EDIT: I've changed to jQuery, which seems simpler. Apparently the problem really is teh cross-server (I've managed to get the data if the script is in the same server) security or permissions within the web-browser (Firefox).. Anyone knows a way around this?

EDIT2: We managed to solve it using JSON... thanks for the replies anyway!

Comment: What you might want to try is take whatever URL you are giving to the XMLHttpRequest and visit that URL in your web browser.  Your browser should let you see the output from the script.  Perhaps your script isn't actually returning anything.

Comment: I tried that, and it is returning the output.. We tried with text/html, text/xml, and it would show on the browser by putting the url there.. It just doesn't work when we try to make a call from the javascript. The request is successful (readyState=4) but the responseText is "".. and it obviously shouldn't be..
Any other way to do it would also be helpfull..

Comment: Is the Python script running on a different domain from the page with JavaScript?  You may be running into a problem with this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your XMLHttpRequest is failing because you're trying to do a cross-domain request. You could use a cross-domain solution like [JSONP](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/107136.aspx) instead.

In general, tools like [Firebug net panel](http://getfirebug.com/net.html) are really useful for debugging these types of problems--you can use them to tell whether the client is sending a request correctly, and whether the server is responding correctly.